# How do I select posts that match all the required tags?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns, blog post ids and tag ids. A blog post can have several tags like it's a post about "New York" and "Soho". Let's say I want to find all the blog posts that have BOTH tag id 1 and 2, how do I do that?

```
blogPostToTags
=============================
id           |tagId
-----------------------------
1            |1
1            |2
2            |1
3            |2
```

UPDATE:

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT id FROM blogPostToTags WHERE tagId = 1 AND tagId = 2
```

and

```
SELECT id FROM blogPostToTags WHERE tagId = 1 OR tagId = 2
```

neither work...

Comment: What have you tried? What pages of documentation have you read? This is not http://do-it-for-me.com

Comment: so i've tried 
select id from blogPostToTags where tagId = 1 AND tag Id = 2 but that just gets me no rows. If I change it to OR, then I get all the rows. Look I honestly don't know what to search up if you can even point me in the right direction, I'll go google it.

Comment: You can't program by "googling it". Study the manual.

Comment: seriously, why even bother answering this question if you're like that?

Comment: If you can't see that I'm trying to mould you into a better programmer, a more analytical thinker, rather than just a part of the "entitled" generation ("google it and get the code"), then that's a shame. Also please format your posts.

Comment: look this is a forum right? all you had to do was say something like, "what you want to do is an example of [something], if you google it, you'll learn more about it." that's it. i'm not asking for the answer for the sake of THIS particular answer.

Comment: No, this is _not_ a forum. Telling me how you think that this site should work doesn't change how it _actually_ works. Also getting all sarcy and entitled with me when I spent time on an answer is... well, y'know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double `JOIN`.

```
SELECT id
FROM blogPosts p
INNER JOIN blogPostToTags pt1 ON pt1.id = p.id
INNER JOIN blogPostToTags pt2 ON pt2.id = p.id
WHERE pt1.tagId = 1 AND pt2.tagId = 2;
```

Comment: @newbieProgrammer: look up regular joins. And then do it twice :-)

Comment: I wish there was a better way. Looks like I'm going to write weird code when I'll have variable number of tags to filter with :)

Comment: @merlinbeard: You can use mongodb :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks yes - that is where I am gonna go eventually I guess. Don't want another system that I'll have to manage separately on AWS just yet :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `id`, COUNT(*) FROM
    (SELECT `id` FROM `blogPostToTags` WHERE `tagId` = 1)
    UNION
    (SELECT `id` FROM `blogPostToTags` WHERE `tagId` = 2)
    AS `_`
    -- this temporary table contains an entry for each `id` when
    -- the tag ID matches. I assume that `id`,`tagId` is a UNIQUE key.
    -- COUNT(*) will be '2' for any `id` with both matches.
WHERE `n` = 2
GROUP BY `id`
```

I don't have an installation of MySQL handy so this is not tested, but it is instead a best-guess designed to send you on the way.

Comment: Thank you ok, I appreciate the answer and the help. I'll go read the manual about unions in queries. That's all I was looking for. Don't worry next time I'll make extra extra sure the answer I need is online somewhere in a reference before I bother asking on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this should work

```
SELECT * FROM items i
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT NULL
FROM blogPostToTags tg
WHERE tg.tagID IN ({tag_comma_separated_values})
AND tg.itemID = i.id
GROUP BY tg.itemID
HAVING COUNT(tg.tagID) = {tag_count}
)
```

in your case

```
SELECT * FROM items i
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT NULL
FROM blogPostToTags tg
WHERE tg.tagID IN (1,2)
AND tg.itemID = i.id
GROUP BY tg.itemID
HAVING COUNT(tg.tagID) = 2
)
```