# mysql many-to-many search

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `skill` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_skill` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `skill_id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`skill_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  ;
```

The table `user_skill` acts as the many-to-many table. Now i want to select all users  having `skill_id`s **atleast** 1 & 2. How can i do that in mysql

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760574/how-do-i-select-posts-that-match-all-the-required-tags?rq=1

or

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176934/select-with-multiple-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select u.id, u.name
from `user` u
inner join `user_skill` us on u.id = us.user_id
where us.skill_id in (1, 2)
group by u.id
having count(distinct us.skill_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The naive way, using `WHERE EXISTS`:

```
SELECT id
FROM `user` u
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM user_skill s WHERE s.user_id = u.id AND s.skill_id = 1)
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM user_skill s WHERE s.user_id = u.id AND s.skill_id = 2)
```

Using two joins:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM `user` u
INNER JOIN user_skill s1 ON s.user_id = u.id AND s.skill_id = 1
INNER JOIN user_skill s2 ON s.user_id = u.id AND s.skill_id = 2
```

Using `HAVING COUNT`:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM `user` u
INNER JOIN user_skill s ON s.user_id = u.id
WHERE s.skill_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```